# How to load two separate pages to two separate iframes?

Tags: iframe

I have a web page with two iframes: iframe.main and iframe.secondary. I was wondering if there's a way to load a specific page to iframe.secondary as the page in iframe.main is loaded? I'll try to illustrate what I want to achieve:

```
<body>

 <iframe id="main" src="">

 </iframe>

 <iframe id="secondary" src="">

 </iframe>

 <button onClick="main.location.href='mainpage.html'">
  Load mainpage.html to iframe.main and secondary.html to iframe.secondary
 </button>

</body>
```

So how do I load secondary.html to iframe.secondary as mainpage.html loads to iframe.main? Can I do it with button's onClick event or mainpage.html's onLoad event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change/set the `src` attribute of the two iframes on button click. Here's an example that also makes your HTML leaner:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Two iframes</title>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function(){
  // Get the button that will trigger the action
  var b = document.getElementById('trigger');
  // and set the onclick handler here instead of in HTML
  b.onclick = doLoads;

  // The callback function for the onclick handler above
  function doLoads() {
      // Get the two iframes
      var m = document.getElementById('main');
      var s = document.getElementById('secondary');
      // and set the source URLs
      m.src = "mainpage.html";
      s.src = "secondary.html";
  }

  // You could also move doLoads() code into an anonymous function like this:
  //     b.onclick = function () { var m = ... etc. }
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="main" src=""></iframe>
<iframe id="secondary" src=""></iframe>
<br>
<button id="trigger">Load both pages</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Next I was thinking about the following: let's assume that iframe.secondary would have some default page, let's call it default.html. How do I change the loaded page in iframe.secondary to default.html as I leave the page in iframe.main?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "leave the page in iframe.main". You could set the initial `src` for the secondary iframe to "default.html" and add another button to re-set it to that after loading "secondary.html". For more complex interactions, I suggest you look into jQuery or some other framework, as plain JavaScript tends to get unwieldy.

Comment: Another question (sorry): What about setting an body onload event to main.html, that triggers the loading of secondary.html in iframe.seconday? I've tried to figure out how to do it but with no success...

Comment: If you want secondary.html to be in the secondary iframe already when the main page loads, do it the simple (normal) way ;) Just write `<iframe id="secondary" src="secondary.html"></iframe>` in your HTML. It would be unnecessary to use JavaScript. The button (and its JS) is only to dynamically change the iframe sources *after* the initial load of main.